ResizeMode not working with lottie-react-native
I'm trying to make a splash screen for my android app using lottie-react-native and I want to make the animation full screen using resizeMode:cover but for some reason resizeMode is not working at all for me. The only way the animation shows up is if I pass in a height and width within the LottieView style prop. Does anyone know why this is happening?
Here is my code:
<View style={{flex: 1,alignItems:'center', margin:0}}>
   <LottieView
     source={require('../assets/xBFpgqn6o0.json')}
     autoPlay
     loop={false}
     resizeMode='cover'
  />
</View>


Try setting position: 'absolute' on the LottieView style.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
